# Как сгенерировать тысячу / миллион / миллиард записей в таблице?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Для оценки производительности моего приложения нужно наполнить БД большим количеством тестовых данных. Встала задача заполнить имеющуюся таблицу автоматически сгенерированными данными. Думал сделать это с помощью одного или нескольких SQL-запросов. Однако столкнулся с затруднением с циклами — кажется, они не дают возможности генерирования произвольных последовательностей. Может быть, есть вариант построить временную таблицу с бесконечным количеством строк, вызывав какую-нибудь встроенную функцию?

К примеру, можно вопрос конкретизировать: как автоматически заполнить таблицу нижеследующими данными?

```
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
|----|----|----|----|
|   0|   1|   0|    |
|   1|   2|   1|    |
|   2|   3|   0|    |
|   4|   4|   1|    |
|   8|   5|   0|    |
|  16|   6|   1|    |
    .   .   .   .
| 2^N| N+1| N%2|  * |
```

<sub>* любая формула по-вашему усмотрению</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пока составлял вопрос — нашёл решение :)

```
INSERT INTO t(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT 2 ^ k, k + 1, k % 2
FROM generate_series(0, N) AS k
```

https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/10/functions-srf